# Switch from Java 8 to Java 11 in my IntelliJ gradle project, a issue comes at runtime

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

I was using Java 8 for my gradle project, now I installed Java 11 & try to switch to using Java 11.

My Java 11 version details:
[image]

My gradle project has following configuration in `build.gradle` file:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.5.3'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.my.webapp.xi'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '11'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
...
...
```

As you can see above I have `sourceCompatibility = '11'` now, it used to be `sourceCompatibility = '8'`.

In my IntelliJ  `Project strucutre` settings, I have chosen Java 11 instead of 8 as well:

[image]

There is no issue building the project. But when I run my java gradle project my Intellij gives me this error:

[image]

If above screenshot error is not enough, here is the complete error message from Intellij:

```
> Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-11.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

When I was using Java 8 (in both build.gradle & the settings of Intellij) it was fine without any issue but when I switch to Java 11 this issue comes,

I also tried switching to Java 16, I get the same issue.

What am I missing? What could be the reason? Where should I check?

Comment: Please share you exact issue.

Comment: @akortex I have now provided the full line of error from IntelliJ. Sorry, I didn't know the screenshot is not complete.

Comment: Have you tried to manually execute the mentioned `java` executable in a terminal? May be your Java installation is simply defect.

Comment: @anatoli why `assembleandroidtest` ? My project is not an android project.

Comment: @Robert it can't be the reason you speculated, because I also tried other Java versions, same issue.

Comment: @user842225 As mentioned above, can you please share the full error? This is just the last line, which is not very helpful in troubleshooting the real error cause.

Comment: Have you updated `JAVA_HOME` in Window's Environmental Variables ?

Comment: @akortex That is the only line of error. Let me provide the screenshot to convince you.  I would provide more if I could.

Answer (score 0):

After I restarted my IntelliJ, the error disappeared.

@akortex, I would like to take a screenshot to convince you that line of error is the only message on console. But I can't reproduce it anymore. If I misunderstand you, it would be nice if you could tell more about "full error", do you mean some other places to check the error or use some command with verbose flag?